# VBA - generating unique numbers in code

Tags: vba, numbers, unique

Is there any way in which I can generate a unique number in code ? 
I had an idea of using system time for that, but eventually could not implement it.

Comment: how many digit u need ?

Comment: What's the context? Is this code that generates unique values until done? Or does it run on a schedule/intermittently and needs to generate unique values anytime it is run? If it runs continuously until done, for example, just generate a variable and increment by 1 every time you need a new one. Could you use a hidden worksheet and use a particular cell that you increment every time you need a new number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Now()` then format the output to a number:

```
Sub unique()    
    Dim t As Date
    t = Now()
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("A1") = CStr(Format(t, "yyyymmddhhMMss"))
End Sub
```

This would be unique.

As @Vasily pointed out, without formatting the cell as string and placing the number as a sting the value gets truncated to scientific notation.

Comment: I think that better is `Cstr(Format(now(), "yyyymmddhhMMssms"))`

Comment: @Vasily The OP clearly asked for a number.  The `Format(now(), "yyyymmddhhMMssms")` is a string and the `Cstr()` wrapper is not needed.

Comment: I mean that if you will inrease range of digits for unique identifyer `CDbl` with format `"yyyymmddhhMMssms"`, it will return a `number+16`, VBA doesn't has `bigint` (e.g. as in SQL Server), that is why my proposal was to use string instead of number. Does not matter number or string in case if the identifyer is unique.

Comment: @Vasily Ah, that makes sense.  You are correct.  Without formatting the cell as string and placing the number as a string it truncates the number in scientific format.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

especially for such cases the GUID (Global Unique IDentifyer) was invented. It may be a little bit oversized ... but just that you have seen it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type TYP_GUID
    bytes(15) As Byte
End Type

Public Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "OLE32.dll" _
                       (guid As TYP_GUID) As Long

Public Function newGUID() As TYP_GUID
    Dim uGUID As TYP_GUID
    CoCreateGuid uGUID
    newGUID = uGUID
End Function
```

whenever you call newGUID() you will become a value that should be really unique in world. You can try and call it as often as you want ... you will never get the same value a second time.

it's also possible to convert such GUID's to string:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type TYP_GUID
    bytes(15) As Byte
End Type

Public Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "OLE32.dll" _
                       (guid As TYP_GUID) As Long

Public Declare Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "OLE32.dll" _
                       (guid As TYP_GUID, _
                        ByVal lpszString As String, _
                        ByVal iMax As Long) As Long

Public Function newGUID() As TYP_GUID
    Dim uGUID As TYP_GUID
    CoCreateGuid uGUID
    newGUID = uGUID
End Function

Public Function newGUID_String() As String
    Dim sBuffer As String
    Dim lResult As Long

    sBuffer = VBA.Space(78)
    lResult = StringFromGUID2(newGUID, sBuffer, Len(sBuffer))
    newGUID_String = Left$(StrConv(sBuffer, vbFromUnicode), lResult - 1)
End Function
```